# Full Screen Image Viewer Similar to Google Photos? - Android

Tags: android, image, photoviewer

Is there an Android plug-in that's similar in functionality to Google Photos, when you click an image and it goes full screen?

Some key functionality too would being able to drag the photo around on screen when it's in full screen mode, and expanding from the thumbnail.

Comment: I think what you want is Shared Element Transition. In that scenario you share the ImageView.

Comment: Thanks Keshav, I will look into the Shared Element Transition

Comment: What you can do is RecyclerView with Images and then transition the image to a PhotoView inside a ViewPager.

Comment: This won't work with pre-lollipop?

Comment: You need to look for other libraries for PreLollipop transition. Android only allow from Lollipop and above.

Comment: https://github.com/stfalcon-studio/FrescoImageViewer